# Linq to SQL - Use slightly different versions of database in same project without creating seperate projects (in C# MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I have a long running MVC webservice project in which I use Linq to SQL to do all my transactions.
Now a table has to be altered, 6 new columns have to be added (all allow null).

Is there a way to keep one visual studio project but that uses 2 different DataClasses.dbml files, based upon a setting or something similar?
This way I don't have to update all my other (non-db) changes in 2 visual studio projects later on. Because I will keep using the old database version and will update the webservice also for the old version.

Thanks in advance for any tips or tricks.

Comment: Am I to understand you're going to have 2 versions of the service, one using the old data structure, and one using to the new? Do you use a source control system? This sounds like a good use case for branching and merging.

Comment: No because EF doesn't recognize the table if it doesn't match the DB table. You have to update the file, To work with a custom Datastructure you have to do that yourself in the code like @ADyson pointed out.

Comment: I taught there might have been another solution to it, but i've been searching some more and it seems like that is a drawback of Linq to SQL (it's also probably not made with these kinds of setups in mind).
@ADyson Yes some of my customers use the old database type but still want the new features that are not database related. while new customers want the latest version. and keeping all the seperate VS projects up to date would be a lot of extra work that I want to prevent.

Comment: that's why I suggested using branching and merging in your source control. One branch for the old version, one branch for the new. If you make changes in one branch which you want to port to the other, you simply merge them across. You may get the odd conflict, but if you keep your code clean and well designed that should be a small issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gone give that a try. Does Visual studio have it's own branching and merging features? Or is a third party software necessary?

Comment: You need some source control software such as Git, SubVersion, TFS etc etc. But they all have ways to integrate nicely into Visual Studio so you can make it part of your workflow. With Git you can have a local repository on your machine without need for a remote service, which is nice. You can also mirror/backup that repository online for free if you have a Microsoft account - see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/02/10/get-your-code-hosted-for-free-in-vsts/ . Or you could use GitHub for the same purpose if your code can be made public.